# C++ Linker error on template class and template function

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11, templates

**Test.h**

```
typedef enum oflags_t : uint8_t
{
    FLAG_CREAT = O_CREAT  
  , FLAG_RONLY = O_RDONLY  
  , FLAG_RDWR = O_RDWR  
} oflags_t;

template <uint8_t flags>
class Test {

public:

    template <uint8_t flags_in = flags>
    Test(const std::string &p_name);

};

using Test_1 = Test<FLAG_RONLY>;
```

**Test.cpp**

```
template <uint8_t flags>
template <uint8_t flags_in>
Test<flags>::Test(const std::string &p_name) {

}

template class Test<FLAG_RONLY>;
```

main.cpp

```
 Test_1 obj1("Obj");
```

When i try to build this, i get linker error "unresolved external symbol...".

What can i do to solve the issue? Thank you.

Comment: You only explicitly instantiate the class template, but you also need to instantiate the constructor.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: "you also need to instantiate the constructor." - because it is an template function?

Comment: @Ionut `template Test<FLAG_RONLY>::Test<FLAG_RONLY>(const std::string &p_name);` @generic_opto_guy Yes.